# C program keeps giving me the same output of 0.00?

Tags: c, function, math, precision

I'm new to c, and my input is 16.7 and 28.6, this is my code,
I need to know why I'm only getting 0.00 as an answer,
has to save height radius and pi as double's
any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


float coneSurfaceArea(double radius, double height, const double pi);


int main()
{
    double radius;
    double height;
    const double pi = 3.14;
    
    printf("Enter the radius: ");
    scanf("%lf", &radius);
    printf("Enter the height: ");
    scanf("%lf", &height);
    printf("The total surface area of the cone is %.2f", coneSurfaceArea);
    return 0;
}

float coneSurfaceArea(double radius, double height, const double pi)
{
    float SA = pi * radius * (radius + sqrt(radius * radius + height * height));
    return SA;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to print the **address** of function `coneSurfaceArea`.

Comment: You need to print its **returned value** by calling it, i.e., `coneSurfaceArea(radius, height, pi)`.

Comment: Aside: don't switch to the junior `float` when you are working with `double`.

Comment: If your compiler didn't say something like `warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'float (*)(double, double, const double)'`, do yourself a favor and get a better compiler, or turn up the warning level on the compiler you do have.

Comment: Also the dreadful `const double pi = 3.14;` should not be a function argument. The ***π*** should be `M_PI` defined in `math.h`. (With MSVC you'll also need `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES`).

Comment: Explain to your nearest rubber duck what coneSurfaceArea is. What other entities of the same kind are used in your program? How is one supposed to use them?

Comment: @WeatherVane last time I checked M_PI wasn't a part of the C standard (which is a shame really). Did they add it in C18 or something?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. `atan(1) * 4` ??

Comment: bbbbbbbbb, that did it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever compiler you're using, turn on its optional warnings (diagnostics, whatever your compiler calls them)! No halfway decent compiler would accept this code without complaining, but unfortunately many compilers default to emitting very few warnings.

GCC does point out the problem, even by default.

```
a.c:18:54: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float (*)(double,  double,  const double)’ [-Wformat=]
   18 |     printf("The total surface area of the cone is %.2f", coneSurfaceAre);
      |                                                   ~~~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                      |   |
      |                                                      |   float (*)(double,  double,  const double)
      |                                                      double
```

In case you're not familiar with the syntax: `float (*)(…)` is the type of a pointer to a function taking arguments as described inside the second pair of parentheses, and returning a `float` value. `coneSurfaceAre` is a function, and since C mostly doesn't manipulate functions as such, a function is treated as a pointer to the function in most contexts.

The `printf` function expects a value of type `double`, but you're passing a pointer to a function. Depending on the system, this may result in printing a meaningless value, a crash, the program continuing but with corrupted memory, etc.

When you want the value returned by a function, you need to *call* this function, passing it arguments. Using the same names for variables in the `main` function and in the `coneSurfaceArea` function may help humans, but as far as the computer is concerned, these are completely different variables.

```
    printf("The total surface area of the cone is %.2f",
           coneSurfaceArea(radius, height, pi));
```

You could pass other values if you wanted.

```
    printf("The total surface area of a cone with twice the height is %.2f",
           coneSurfaceArea(radius, 2 * height, pi));
```

By the way, printf with the `%f` format expects a `double` argument¹. Here, you're passing a `float`. This is actually correct because of *promotions*: when you pass certain “small” types to a function like `printf` that takes a variable number of arguments, they are promoted to a larger type, e.g. `short` to `int` and `float` to `double`. But in more complex cases you could run into problems if you aren't careful. It's generally simpler to stick to `double`. And using `double` all the time is often slightly *faster* than using `float`, because using `float` just results in the same calculations followed by a conversion. There is an advantage to `float` when the program manipulates a lot of numbers, because then you can save memory and, in some cases, take advantage of vector instructions that can perform two independent `float` operations just as fast as one `double` operation.

¹  <sub>Unlike `scanf`, which does need a pointer to `float` for `%f`, and a pointer to `double` for `%lf`.</sub>

Comment: @SteveSummit And you could have saved yourself some time by not posting this comment. Your point?